# Change Password Angular implementation Validations not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-validate

I have created a Change Password Page using Angular JS which is having 3 fields -
 1. Old Password
 2. new Password
 3. Confirm new password

The validations i am trying to impose is -
1. User opens the form and clicks submit directly without clicking anywhere. This should trigger all the 3 error messages for all 3 input types.
2. The passwords are validated with respect to a regex, failing to which error message should be triggered.
3. New password and Confirm password should match.

Issue i am facing is -
Suppose i enter 2 digits in old password , press a tab and go to new password, error message is displayed in front of Old password. Similarily if i enter 2 digits in new password and press tab to navigate to Confirm New password, error message is getting triggered.But if i try to fill the form from bottom to top with invalid inputs, error meesages are only getting triggered when i reach the top input element, i.e. old password

The 2 directives i have created are -

```
     .directive('passwordValidate', ['regularExpression', function (regex) {
     return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
             elm.unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
             elm.bind('blur', function (viewValue) {
                 scope.$apply(function () {
                     if ((regex.PASSWORD).test(viewValue.target.value)) {
                         // it is valid
                         ctrl.$setValidity('passwordValidate', true);
                         return viewValue;
                     } else {
                         // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
                         ctrl.$setValidity('passwordValidate', false);
                         return undefined;
                     }
                 });
             });
         }
     };
 }])
.directive('passwordMatch', function($parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
            elm.bind('blur', function (viewValue) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return $parse(attrs.passwordMatch)(scope) === ctrl.$modelValue;
                }, function (currentValue) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('passwordMismatch', currentValue);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

i have created a JS Fiddle for the same - http://jsfiddle.net/achyut/Z367L/18/

I am afraid i am doing something wrong with the events (blur, change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fiddle you have provided I can see the logic or condition for showing error message for new password is dependent on old password field being dirty.(_ServerForm.oldpassword.$dirty)

```
<span class="ui-state-error h5-message" ng-show="(_ServerForm.oldpassword.$dirty && _ServerForm.oldpassword.$error.passwordValidate) || (blankSubmit && _ServerForm.oldpassword.$invalid)">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a typo in expression which shows/hides the error message. Take a look at the last one:

```
<span class="ui-state-error h5-message" ng-show="(_ServerForm.oldpassword.$dirty && _ServerForm.newpasswordconfirm.$error.passwordValidate) || (blankSubmit && _ServerForm.newpasswordconfirm.$invalid)">
    <span class="h5-arrow"></span>
    <span class="h5-content">Please type confirm new password</span>
</span>
```

here you check `_ServerForm.oldpassword.$dirty`, so error message will not be shown before old password field is changed. If you remove this check or use `_ServerForm.newpasswordconfirm.$dirty` instead then all will work fine.

The same story is for `newpassword` field too.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. both the answers are right, accepted based on the timing